# Android Google Maps Api Tileprovider reapeating x

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps, tiles

i want to build a map for my app with custom tiles

here is the code of my tiles provider:

```
    TileProvider tileProvider = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {
        @Override
        public synchronized URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {

            Integer tileRange = 1 << zoom;

            if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
                return null;
            }


            String s = String.format(Locale.US, MOON_MAP_URL_FORMAT, zoom, x, y);
            URL url = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(s);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            }



            return url;
        }
    };

    mMoonTiles = map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider));
```

but the problem is that when is scroll right the map repeats the tiles. This problem does not occur when i scrolling top or bottom.
Is it possible to disable this repeating for the x axis?

I have already tested

```
if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
                    return null;
}
```

from the google maps api documentation.
I know that the normal google maps repeats the x axis, too. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/byva9.png

Comment: Can you post a picture so we can see what it looks like?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByxUjhRGdx9jaEg1MWIyMHRmQlU/edit?usp=docslist_api here you can see that the map reapeats always on x axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) { ...`

to

```
if (x < 0 || x > tileRange - 1) { ...
```

Comment: when i change this it never calles